# Visual Studio C++ But Without Dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My code works fine when I have it but when my friend runs the simple cout code, he needs MSVC140D.dll and found nothing. I do have the .dll in my system32 but I don't understand [Microsoft's redistribution method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kche8ah.aspx) so I'm wondering if there is a easier way.

Comment: A short explanation and instruction here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6badcd6-297d-4c73-a589-02507eb79548/statically-link-msvcdlls?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Alternatively your friend can download the msvc redistributable package

Comment: I mean it would work for them to download the package, but that's not practical

Comment: Also the short explanation didn't seem to work

Comment: `MSVC140D.dll` is a debug DLL. I don't believe these ship with the runtime redistributable package, and you don't want to ship debug builds anyway. A debug build is optimized for ease of debugging, and that's close to useless without the VS IDE to do the debugging. PLUS the debug build has not been optimized for speed or size so the executable will likely be freaking huge and pitifully slow compared to the release executable. There is a drop-down up at the top of the IDE that currently says Debug. Switch it to Release and rebuild, then send the release executable to your friend.

Comment: Probably at least a dozen duplicates.

Comment: Don't know what a dozen duplicates means but ok. Also, thanks user I forgot that even existed